# How to make CSS layout with fluid row height limited by child's max-height?

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design

**Layout:**

There is a container that fills 100% of window's height. Inside it there are two `.parent` boxes (filled red) which contain `.child` elements (filled yellow). Child elements have `min-height` and `max-height` set.

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    height: 100%;
    gap: 20px;
}

.parent {
    background: #f00;
}

.nested {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.child {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 150px;

    background: #ff0;
}

.another-child {
    flex: none;
    height: 50px;

    background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="nested">
      <div class="another-child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Goal:**

Make `.parent` boxes grow vertically only till child elements `max-height` if there is space inside `.container` and shrink to `min-height` if there isn't. Parent block red background should not be visible.

Comment: have you tried similar to this : https://css-tricks.com/boxes-fill-height-dont-squish/

Comment: You can't have a min-height of a child based on the space available inside a parent.

Comment: I did not really understand your Goal , have you tried height:fit-content on .parent ?

Comment: Now I understand it's impossible to solve the goal with CSS to make child's height responsive based on available window's space. Thanks.